# Evaluate $\int_a^b \sqrt{(1+ m^2\cosh^2x)}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_a^b \sqrt{(1+ m^2\cosh^2x)}dx$$ where $a = 0$ and $b= \ln 2$

I just need a little hint to start. Please don't answer it completely. Just a hint.

Edit : Originally the question was to find the arc length of the curve $f(x) = m \sinh x$ on the interval $[0, \ln 2]$. But I cannot evaluate this integral at all.

Comment: Hint.  Elliptic integral.

Comment: The $dx$ is missing, although it seems clear that $x$ is the integration variable, while $m$ is a fixed parameter.

Comment: I have no idea about elliptic integration. Can not it be solved by regular methods?

Comment: Was this problem on a section about numerical integration? For an arbitrary $m$, it's almost certainly the case that this integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions the constants we know and love (rational numbers, $\pi$, $e$, etc).

Comment: @Alann no it was not. I just got the question as it is. It was originally a question to evaluate the arc length. I've edited my question and mentioned it. So as u said that it cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions then I suppose this is beyond my course level.

Comment: Maybe $\int_0^{\ln 2} \sqrt{(1+ m^2\cosh^2x)\,}\;dx$ is the intended answer to the question.

Comment: @GEdgar if, as you mentioned, it can be evaluated by elliptical integration then I suppose the answer is not intended to be what you mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

$$ I = \int_0^{\ln(2)}  \sqrt{(1+ m^2\cosh^2x)}dx$$

As other user pointed out in the comments this integral is an elliptic integral and there is no way to deal with it out of the theory of elliptic integrals if you want to express it in a closed form.

Do the following change of variable $w = ix$, then :

$$ I = i \int_0^{-i\ln(2)} \sqrt{1+ m^2\cos^2 w}dw  = i \int_0^{-i\ln(2)} \sqrt{1+ m^2(1-\sin^2 w)}dw =  i \int_0^{-i\ln(2)} \sqrt{1+ m^2-m^2\sin^2 w}dw = i\sqrt{1+m^2}\int_0^{-i\ln(2)} \sqrt{1-\frac{m^2}{1+m^2}\sin^2 w} $$

Recall the definiton of the incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind:

$$E(p,\phi) = \int_{0}^{\phi} \sqrt{1-p^2\sin^2 \theta}d\theta \quad q^2=1-p^2$$

where $p$ is the *modulus* and $q$ is the *complementary modulus*. $\phi$ is  named the *amplitude*

Hence,

in your case $p^2 = \frac{m^2}{1+m^2}$ is the modulus, $\phi = -i\ln(2)$ is the amplitude.

$$I = i\sqrt{1+m^2}E\left(\sqrt{\frac{m^2}{1+m^2}},-i\ln(2) \right) $$

In principle, $p$ is real and $|p|<1$ but the theory can be extended to consider complex modulus.

Same thing with the amplitude: the basic theory states that $0\leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. However, the theory can be extended to imaginary amplitudes, as is the case with your integral.

For imaginary amplitude, the incomplete elliptic integral are themselves imaginary and involve the [guadermanian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function) as well as hyperbolic functions:

$$E(p,i\phi) = i\left[F(q,\operatorname{gd}(\phi))-E(q,\operatorname{gd}(\phi)) + \tanh(\phi)\sqrt{1+p^2\sinh^2(\phi)}\right]$$

where $F(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind:

$$F(p,\phi) = \int_{0}^{\phi} \frac{d\phi}{\sqrt{1-p^2\sin^2 \theta}}d\theta$$

Hence, your integral expressed in clsed form is:

$$I = \sqrt{1+m^2}\left[F\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}},\operatorname{gd}(-\ln(2))\right)-E\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}},\operatorname{gd}(-\ln(2))\right)-\frac{3}{5}\sqrt{1+\frac{m^2}{1+m^2}\frac{9}{16}}\right]$$

where

$$ q = \sqrt{1-p^2 }= \sqrt{1-\frac{m^2}{1+m^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$$

Wolfram evaluates $\operatorname{gd}(-\ln(2)) = 2\cot^{-1}(2)-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Take care when evaluating ellptic integrals with software given that someties they use a [slight different notation](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE2/introductions/IncompleteEllipticIntegrals/01/).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know yet about elliptic integrals, you do not have much choice.

Start using
$$\cosh^2(x)=\frac 1 2(1+\cosh(2x))$$ which makes
$$1+m^2\cosh^2(x)=\frac{1}{2} m^2 \cosh (2 x)+\frac{m^2}{2}+1=\frac{1}{2} m^2\Big[1+\frac{2}{m^2}+\cosh (2 x) \Big]$$

Now, use the series expansion of $\cosh(2x)$. This will give

$$1+m^2\cosh^2(x)=\left(m^2+1\right)+m^2 x^2+\frac{m^2}{3} x^4+\frac{2 m^2 }{45}x^6+\frac{m^2  }{315} x^8+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$
Use the binomial theorem
$$\sqrt{1+m^2\cosh^2(x)}=\sqrt{m^2+1}+\frac{m^2 x^2}{2 \sqrt{m^2+1}}+\frac{m^2 \left(m^2+4\right) x^4}{24
   \left(m^2+1\right)^{3/2}}+\frac{m^2 \left(m^4-28 m^2+16\right) x^6}{720
   \left(m^2+1\right)^{5/2}}+\frac{m^2 \left(m^6+696 m^4-816 m^2+64\right) x^8}{40320
   \left(m^2+1\right)^{7/2}}+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$ Integrate termwise to have an approximate antiderivative. Use the bounds.

Suppose that, with your given bounds, we use this truncated series for $m=3$. This would give as a numerical result $2.3547717$ while using the elliptic integral, the result would be $2.3547702$.

Answer (score 1):

---

Define the function $\mathcal{I}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(s,\omega\right)}:=\int_{0}^{\omega}\mathrm{d}\nu\,\sqrt{1+s^{2}\cosh^{2}{\left(\nu\right)}}.$$

As @zinoviev's answer illustrates, the integral actually becomes pretty straightforward once you are sufficiently well-versed in the properties and relations of elliptic integrals. But the involvement of complex variables is a layer of complication I'd rather avoid for elliptic integral newbies.

The following approach may be more longwinded, but it has the appeal of sticking to real variables.

---

Given $0<s\land0<\omega$ and setting $z:=\cosh{\left(\omega\right)}>1$,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(s,\omega\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\omega}\mathrm{d}\nu\,\sqrt{1+s^{2}\cosh^{2}{\left(\nu\right)}}\\
&=\int_{\cosh{\left(0\right)}}^{\cosh{\left(\omega\right)}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{1+s^{2}x^{2}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}};~~~\small{\left[\nu=\ln{\left(x+\sqrt{x^{2}-1}\right)}\right]}\\
&=\int_{1}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\sqrt{1+s^{2}x^{2}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}\\
&=\int_{1}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1+s^{2}x^{2}}{\sqrt{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}x^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\int_{1}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}x^{2}\right)}}+\int_{1}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{s^{2}x^{2}}{\sqrt{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}x^{2}\right)}}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Consider the following derivative:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\sqrt{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}x^{2}\right)}}{x}\right]=\frac{s^{2}x^{4}+1}{x^{2}\sqrt{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}x^{2}\right)}}.$$

This leads to the integration formula

$$\int_{1}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{s^{2}x^{2}}{\sqrt{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}x^{2}\right)}}=\frac{\sqrt{\left(z^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}z^{2}\right)}}{z}-\int_{1}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x^{2}\sqrt{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}x^{2}\right)}}.$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(s,\omega\right)}
&=\int_{1}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}x^{2}\right)}}+\int_{1}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{s^{2}x^{2}}{\sqrt{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}x^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\int_{1}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}x^{2}\right)}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\sqrt{\left(z^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}z^{2}\right)}}{z}-\int_{1}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{x^{2}\sqrt{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}x^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\left(z^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}z^{2}\right)}}{z}+\int_{1}^{z}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1-x^{-2}}{\sqrt{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}x^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\left(z^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}z^{2}\right)}}{z}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\tan{\left(\varphi\right)}\sec{\left(\varphi\right)}\left[\sec^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}-1\right]}{\sec^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\sqrt{\left[\sec^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}-1\right]\left[1+s^{2}\sec^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}\right]}};~~~\small{\left[x=\sec{\left(\varphi\right)}\right]}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\left(z^{2}-1\right)\left(1+s^{2}z^{2}\right)}}{z}+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin{\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}}\mathrm{d}\varphi\,\frac{\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}{\sqrt{1+s^{2}-\sin^{2}{\left(\varphi\right)}}}.\\
\end{align}$$

It should be clear how to proceed from this point, so I leave the rest as an exercise for the reader.

---

Answer (score 0):

Put $ x\to ix$.

We get elliptic integrals in closed form as for example similar to computing circumference of an ellipse.

Now put back $ x \to - ix $ again to put result  back to hyperbolic functions.

Comment: This could be a comment, but good insight.

Comment: Was not really a casual comment, since the computation of the circumference of ellipse is fairly well known like e.g., MathWorld, 2D curves etc. I did not copy it once again.

Comment: Was not really a casual comment, Now made an answer, since the computation of the circumference of ellipse is fairly well known like e.g., MathWorld, 2D curves etc. I did not copy it once again.

Comment: You did copy the above comment as seen [in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7j32.jpg).

Comment: i think it anwers without repearing the known part. Do you suggest I mention the known stuff (ellipse circumference derivation) once  again?